# Generalisation of the Hopf–Rinow theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, global-analysis

Is their a generalisation of the Hopf–Rinow theorem to infinite dimensional manifolds (Frechet, Banach or Hilbert)?

I have actually never seen the prove of the Hopf–Rinow theorem so i don't know if their are obvious generalisations.

Comment: The direct generalization is false - you can find a discussion of the failure in Chapter VIII of Lang's *Fundamentals of Differential Geometry*, along with a different sufficient condition for completeness in the case of Hilbert manifolds. If you're looking for generalizations to particular settings then it should be fairly googleable.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thank you for the reference